# Problems installing boorstrap angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've been searching some queations to solve a problem installing the ng-bootstrap but i can solve it
I have w10, VSCode 1.65.2, angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.3
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.3
@angular-devkit/core         13.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.2.3
@angular/cli                 13.2.3
@schematics/angular          13.2.3
```

I've open a cmd terminal into vsc and type ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap as instalation said, but I can do it. This is my error

```
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1327 bytes)
⠸ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-firebase@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"13.2.6" from @angular/compiler-cli@13.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~13.2.0" from the root project      
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ngtools/webpack)
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/localize@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"13.2.7" from @angular/localize@13.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!     @angular/localize@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\pcb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pcb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-18T12_03_16_626Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

And finally this is my jsom

```
{  "name": "angular-firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^11.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Could you help me and leave the instuctions as i were stupid (step by step)

Kind regards

PaCaBo

Comment: You can try removing the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder, then run another `npm install`. See how that goes for you.

Comment: Simply do this: ```npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps```

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks

Comment: @KibéM.C, is the correct answer imho.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your *node_modules* folder and *package-lock.json* file. After follow the steps,

Run

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

then

`npm install`